# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory When I use subprocess.Popen in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a problem with Python when I use subprocess.Popen (in ubuntu). I have a code like this:

```
# This line is just to check if the path are right. 
# I can delete this first Popen but I get always the same error.
out = subprocess.Popen(["ls"], cwd='/home/user/Desktop/',
   stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

print out

# This line doesn't work
out = subprocess.Popen(["mri_info", "--vox2ras", "orig.mgz"], 
    cwd='/home/user/Desktop/',
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

print out
```

The first Popen works very well but the second one no. It gives me this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I'm sure that the path are right and the file orig.mgz is in that directory but... it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: Try it with the absolute path.

Comment: if the absolute path in ubuntu is something like /home/user/directory/ i'm using it

Comment: Say the docs "If cwd is not None, the child’s current directory will be changed to cwd before it is executed. Note that this directory is not considered when searching the executable, so you can’t specify the program’s path relative to cwd." If you are actually using the absolute path `/home/user/directory/mri_info` please edit your question to show it. I suspect that you aren't.

Comment: the path that I'm actually using is `/home/user/Desktop/` (for both the subprocess.Popen)

Comment: The fact still remains that the error message could be because `mri_info` is not found, not because the `orig.mgz` file is not found. Read the comment again.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if the problem is `mri_info` the output should be something like `mri_info: command not found`